# Find intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I completed this problem in which I have to find the intersection of two planes. How is it that I can assume the point of intersection is at z=0? May someone please elaborate.

[image]

Comment: Please take also a look to [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to present your derivation in  a proper way. Thanks

Comment: Sorry man, first question ever posted on Mathematics.

Comment: That's fine, your work looks very good and well presented. Using mathjax is also very important for the quality of the site.

Comment: Actually, you are guessing that there exists a point in the intersection with z=0. If there is no such point, then this method fails, in which case you can make another guess, e.g. x=0, y=0. Note, that any guess is possible, e.g. z=4.